# Is there a way of taking the average of multiple lists of equal size?

Tags: python, list, numpy, average

This is in python.

Let's say I have three lists:

```
x = [[1, 2], [2 , 4], [1, 1]]
y = [[3, 4], [6 , 8], [1, 1]]
z = [[5, 6], [10, 12], [1, 1]]
```

I want to obtain the list

```
avg = [[.. , ..], [.., ..], [.., ..]]
```

and

```
standard_deviation = [[.. , ..], [.., ..], [.., ..]]
```

Where e.g. `avg[0,0] = (1 + 3 + 5)/3`
same for the other values.

Thanks in advance. This will save me a massive amount of time.

Comment: You should be able to do this using `zip()` and nested list comprehensions.

Comment: You can also use the `statistics` module to calculate mean and stddev.

Comment: In `avg[0,0] = (1 + 3 + 5)/6`  should it be `avg[0,0] = (1 + 3 + 5)/3`?

Comment: @bb1 Yeah exactly. It's late :)

Answer (score 1):

For a numpy 2D array

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 2 , 4, 1, 1],
              [3, 4, 6 , 8, 1, 1],
              [5, 6, 10, 12, 1, 1]])
```

you can simply do `np.mean(a,axis=0)` and `np.std(a,axis=0)`.

You can easily create `a` by doing the following :

```
x, y, z = np.array(x), np.array(y), np.array(z)
x, y, z = np.ndarray.flatten(x), np.ndarray.flatten(y), np.ndarray.flatten(z)
a = np.vstack((x,y,z))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

x = [[1, 2], [2 , 4], [1, 1]]
y = [[3, 4], [6 , 8], [1, 1]]
z = [[5, 6], [10, 12], [1, 1]]

arr = np.dstack([x, y, z])

# mean
arr_mean = arr.mean(axis=-1)
# standard deviation
arr_std = arr.std(axis=-1)

print(f"Mean:\n {arr_mean}\n")
print(f"Std:\n {arr_std}")
```

It gives:

```
Mean:
 [[3. 4.]
  [6. 8.]
  [1. 1.]]

Std:
 [[1.63299316 1.63299316]
  [3.26598632 3.26598632]
  [0.         0.        ]]
```

Comment: I had never seen ndstack before. Thanks a lot!